# AS3, Simple: Changing movieclip properties from inside its Time Line

Tags: properties, parent, movieclip

Another one noobie question.

I have movieclip spaceship_mc on Main Timelime.
Its instance name is spaceship1_mc (added from library manually).
In Library this symbol has 2 layers: Objects layer and Action layer.

I put inside Action layer such simple code:

```
var spaceship1_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
spaceship1_mc.blendMode = BlendMode.SCREEN;
spaceship1_mc.scaleX = 2;
spaceship1_mc.scaleY= 2;
```

I suppose, that at run time this code must work automatically, and all those parameters will be set at the very beginning.

However, nothing changes. As if this code doesn't work.

**QUESTION1**: Please, tell me what is wrong?
Maybe I should use some more complicated dot-syntax?

**QUESTION2**: What is the name of *Main Time Line*?
I tried to use *stage*, *root*, *MainTimeLine*, in the code above, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using google I've found one decision.
Perhaps, It is somewhat redundant and (..Hey...WTF? It's helicopter at the skyline, dudes!...Cool...)... Okay.

And here it is:

```
var ship1:MovieClip = parent.getChildByName("spaceship1_mc") as MovieClip;
ship1.blendMode = BlendMode.SCREEN;
ship1.scaleX = 2;
ship1.scaleY= 2;
```

Well... I suppose it is somewhat too indirect.
So we must read the name of some Instance and determine it as variable.  I guess there must be some more laconic way.